# spresenseで推論可能なSony NNC のサイズについて

Tags: spresense

SpresenseとArduinoの開発環境で、nncで学習したファイルを`dnnrt.forward()`をする時の
「nnbのファイルサイズの大きさ」についていくつか質問があります。

1. 大きさは実行させるコア（メインなのか、サブなのか）に依存しますか？
   使えるメモリサイズ（タイル？）に依存しそうな気がしています。
2. そのときの目安のようなものがありましたら教えてください。
   プログラムはとっても単純で、スタックやヒープなどはほとんど使わないものと仮定して頂いて結構です。
3. ファイルが推論可能かどうか、事前にプログラム等でチェックする方法はないでしょうか？

どうぞよろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 1):

追加で調査しました。

結局、Cameraなどを利用してしまうと、Heapがほとんどなく、結局NNCのnnbファイルを置くエリアが数十バイトになってしまい、思うようなネットワークのAIが組めません。

ですが、Spresenseの1.5MBのメモリのWorker部分には、まだ、空きがあることが多いようです。
そこで、そのエリアからメモリをとってみました。

https://developer.sony.com/develop/spresense/docs/sdk_developer_guide_ja.html#_asmp_framework
を見てもわかりにくいのですが、exampleを参考に、Shared RAMを取得します。

```
  mpshm_t shm;
  int ret = mpshm_init(&shm, 0, 1024*512);
  int8_t* buf = mpshm_attach(&shm, 0);
```

このような感じで、512kBの仮想空間のエリアの取得をmalloc代わりに行うと、

```
size = nnbfile.size();
```

のサイズが、512kBより小さければ、

```
_network = buf;
```

とすれば、512kBのnnbファイルを置くことができるようです。

これで、かなり大きなネットワークのAIが組めますね。

Comment: 編集ありがとうございます。

Comment: 追加調査ありがとうございました。

Answer (score 0):

自分もNNCを使い始めて、NNBファイルのサイズの問題にぶち当たりました。

コードを見る限り、

DNNRT.cpp

のなかので、

```
  size = nnbfile.size();
  _network = (nn_network_t *)malloc(size);
```

といった感じでmallocしているので、おそらくHeapサイズ次第なのでしょう。
なので、Cameraを使って、もろもろのアプリを作っていると、かなりサイズが小さくなってしまうようです。

見る限りアプリが使えるエリアは768kBぐらいしかなさそうなので、カメラなどを使わず、もしアプリが小さかったとしても、300kBぐらいしかheapから取れなそうに見えます。
残りのエリアをうまく活用できるような対応をSONYさんに期待したいですね。

Comment: ご返答、ありがとうござました。ヒープにnnbfileのサイズそのままが確保している、ということがわかり、参考になりました。コンパイル後のメッセージにメモリの使用量が出ましたので、その空き具合が「上限の参考」になるのかもしれません。カメラのもっている画素数で撮影するだけでメモリが足りないのですが、アプリケーションでプログラムが色々できるメモリが搭載されているといいですね・・。